# Failed to open stream: No such file or directory 'tambahuser.php'

Tags: php

> Warning: include(tambahuser.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampppppppp\htdocs\abc\cons\masterpage.php on line 285

> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'tambahuser.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampppppppp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampppppppp\htdocs\abc\cons\masterpage.php on line 285

facing these errors for days, can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

File `tambahuser.php` must be in the same directory as the file `masterpage.php`.

[image]

Result :

[image]

if there is a folder where the file `tambahuser.php` exist, try `include('./folder_name/file.php');`

Comment: It works but doesn't display any interface. Can it be in a different folder? Because before this it was in a different folder and ran perfectly. I did some minor changes and suddenly it turns out like this. 'tambahuser.php' is supposed to be in the 'process' folder which is in 'cons'.